# how can I make a ul,li collapsible with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My list looks like this:

[image]

So the folders have the class `parent` and the files have the lass `child`.

I have tried a few things and others found here on stackoverflow.
Like:

```
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

This works fine if there are folder besides folder. The problem is that I have folders in other folders and it doesn't work properly for this.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: 'folders in other folders' what does it mean?

Comment: Providing a working example will help more to understand your problem.

Comment: @AswinKumar nested folders. I want to achieve A collapsable Directory structure

Comment: @PiyushVerma Like a directory structure in any IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope it solve your problem.

```js
$('.child').hide();
$('.parent').click(function(e) {
e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="parent">
    Parent
    <ul class="child">      
      <li class="parent">
        Parent
        <ul class="child">
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Parent
    <ul class="child">      
      <li class="parent">
        Parent
        <ul class="child">
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Parent
    <ul class="child">      
      <li class="parent">
        Parent
        <ul class="child">
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent">
    Parent
    <ul class="child">      
      <li class="parent">
        Parent
        <ul class="child">
            <li>child</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```